# Unknown column 'b.id2' in 'where clause'

Tags: php

Está dando esse erro:

> Unknown column 'b.id2' in 'where clause'

**Pacotes.php**

```
include ("config.php");
$tabla2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  tb_buyref b, tb_refset r  WHERE r.id=".$id." AND b.id2=".$id)  or die(mysql_error()); // selecciono todos los registros de la tabla usuarios, ordenado por nombre
while($registro2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($tabla2)){
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: `id2` não existe na tabela, imprima a sql e teste direto no banco.

Comment: @perdeu a tabela deve existir, o que não existe é o campo id2 na tabela tb_buyref

Comment: Tente explicar o objetivo do código e o contexto do problema. Parece que vc quer fazer um `join` na tabelas, para isso é necessário que ambas tenha alguma coluna `id` em comum. A consulta pode reescrita como: `SELECT * FROM  tb_buyref b INNER JOIN tb_refset r ON b.id = r.id WHERE b.id = $id`

Answer (score 1):

> Unknown column 'b.id2' in 'where clause'

O erro diz que não existe a coluna "id2" na tabela "tb_buyref", o "b" na sua query é apenas um alias para a tabela.

Verificou a estrutura da tabela?

Comment: Não apareceu nenhum erro mais também não fez nada.

Comment: @user7329 o campo id2 existe na tabela tb_buyref? já confirmou?

Comment: Não exite então eu mudei o script de id2 para id, Não aparece nenhum erro mais quando vou executar uma função ex: Excluir Referidos ele aparece uma página em branco.

Comment: Se não existe retire essa condição "AND b.id2=".$id", mas antes tente verificar o por quê dessa condição ou se existe outro campo id para substituir.

Comment: @user7329 então o problema foi resolvido, era a coluna "id2" que não existia e sim a coluna "id". Agora o problema é outro, provavelmente a query não está retornando nenhum resultado. Faço o seguinte, após o "mysql_query" verifique se foi encontrado algum registo, da seguinte forma: $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($tabla2); die("foram encontrados $num_rows registos");

Answer (score 0):

tente alterar o nome da coluna conforme adicionado abaixo, provavelmente você se confundiu na hora de colocar o nome e colocou id2, mas isso depende da nomenclatura que você colocou, caso não de certo insira aqui a estrutura do seu banco de dados

```
$tabla2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  tb_buyref b, tb_refset r  WHERE r.id=".$id." AND b.id=".$id)  or die(mysql_error());
```